# What is the legitimate way to Initialize String array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

While doing static analysis of my java project using findbug, I came through a situation where i get null pointer dereference error. 
In some sections of my code, I've used null for head initialization and the actual values assignment takes place during the runtime.

Ex: `String[] strArray = null;`

I've done some workaround to avoid this error,

```
String[] strArray = new String[1];
```

But it pushes me towards a impediment situation. Which makes me feel something is actually incomplete.

Please, someone suggest me an acceptable solution.

Comment: This isn't clear - please show a complete example of the problem.

Comment: `strArray` might be improperly scoped.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Actually the array size is obtained from a SOAP response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should initialise it with the value it should have initially. If the value isn't known you can only do

```
String[] strArray;
```

This means you have no idea what it could be when declared.  If you want it to be initially empty, you can do

```
String[] strArray = { };
```

This is only preferable if this doesn't hide a bug as a result of making it not-null.

Obviously the best option is to give it the correct value from the start, and ideally make it `final`.

```
final String[] strArray;

MyClass(String[] strArray) {
    this.strArray = strArray;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted.